# Set the order of non-builtin tray applications in Icewm

Tags: tray, icewm

I have several applications in my system tray which are not the default monitoring gadgets of Icewm. For example, below you can see, from left to right, [1] **`pnmixer`**, [2] **`nm-applet`**, a keyboard leds indicator [3] **`trayleds.py`**, a brightness indicator [4] **`traybr.py`**, the [5] battery level indicator and the [6] network monitoring widget (the last two are Icewm builtins).

[image: Sample tray icons]

The order of the first four, non-builtin is apparently randomly defined at startup. How may I fix the order for them (say, [2], [4], [1] and [3])? `man icewm-winoptions` mentions

> **order**: NUMBER (default: 0)
>
> The sorting order of task buttons and tray icons. The default value is zero. Increasing positive values go farther right,
> while decreasing negative values
> go farther left. The order option applies to the task pane, the tray pane and the system tray.

but how can I find out the appropriate names to add to `~/.icewm/winoptions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `icesh` to find the terms that should go in `~/.icewm/winoptions`. They are those in the 4th field, as I determined by trial and error:

```
$ icesh systray
0xc00001    0  5981 "pnmixer"           : (pnmixer.Pnmixer)    10x10+10+10
0x1000001   0  5980 "NetworkManager Applet": (nm-applet.Nm-applet) 10x10+10+10
0x1400001   0  5988 "trayleds.py"       : (trayleds.py.Trayleds.py) 10x10+10+10
0x1200001   0  5989 "traybr.py"         : (traybr.py.Traybr.py) 10x10+10+10
```

So, to get [2] **`nm-applet`**, [4] **`traybr.py`**, [1] **`pnmixer`**, [3] **`trayleds.py`** order, this is your  `~/.icewm/winoptions`:

```
NetworkManager Applet.order: +1
traybr.py.order:             +2
pnmixer.order:               +3
trayleds.py.order:           +4
```

The result:

[image: Sample tray icons user-sorted]

Comment: nice :-) Where did you get the tryleds.py from? I googled in vain ...